# Is using a method to simplify typing a command a bad practice?

Tags: c#

For example, say I'm too lazy to type out `Console.Write("text")` and decide to make this:

```
static void w(string text) {
    Console.Write(text);
}
```

And then just call it like this:

```
w("This is a string.");
```

Is it considered a bad practice to make a method that does this for me? Does it matter?

Comment: You know you can make a snippet in VS. In fact, there already is one called `cw` that does exactly what you need!

Comment: What's wrong with typing `cw` and pressing ctrl+space? Isn't that slower and is more readable

Comment: I actually was not aware of either of those. I'm fairly new to using the Visual C#. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For something this trivial, It will **reduce the code readability**. IMO

Please take a look at: [Visual C# Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and there is one `cw` that you can use instead of calling your method.

Answer (score 8):

I'd say it's a bad practice, because it makes the code less readable.

If you're really just too lazy, then you can always work with code snippets.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the code snippets feature before, but I think I'll definitely use that!

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly a bad practise to reduce the readability of your code for the purposes of reducing typing.  Don't forget, your code must be maintainable once it has been completed, whether by you or by someone else.

It's very difficult to determine from the signature what the method w(string text) is intended to do.  However, feel free to abstract out verbose calls to methods if you feel it **increases** the readability.

Answer (score 2):

It's bad for the readability of your code. And if you just introduce a new method for calling one function, I would say that this is bad.

Why don't you want to write Console.Write(...)? Just because you're lazy? The visual-studio (or other ide's) have a great autocomplete.

Comment: I would say it's just laziness, as I'd rather type `w()` than do auto-complete. I'm sure being a lazy programmer is not a great idea!

Comment: @Abluescarab: you can type cwl<tab> and VS will expand that to `Console.WriteLine(<caret here>);` You can create your own code snippets.